# WMI with WCF service

Tags: wcf, wmi

I am trying to enable and use WMI with a WCF service which i have, i have changed the configurations as per the link below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735120.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751442.aspx

```
<diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true" performanceCounters="All">
   <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
```

I am using the WMI object browser to read the WMI data from AppDomainInfo. When I run the service directly from Visual Studio 2010, using the WMI object browser I am able to read the AppDomainInfo data and also modify it also the Logs are creation is working.

If I connect to the service using my ASP.Net application so that the service is accessed and now when I try to access the WMI data from WMI object browser, I get a error message saying no instance of the class AppDomainData.

How can the WMI data be accessed without running the WCF service from Visual studio. Is any other configuration am i missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add aspnet user to ServiceModel security in WMI control as aspnet_wp process runs under aspnet user. With this i was able to access the WMI data in WMI object browser.

Comment: I also have a WCF service and its WMI provider is enabled, i want the client to access wmi of that service to monitor processes, how did you do that, do i have to run that powershell scripts like in MDSN links?